# foundationCLI ENOENT when creating a new project

Tags: ruby, git, zurb-foundation, bundler, bower

So I want to try the new foundation for apps but I can't get past step 2 (http://foundation.zurb.com/apps/getting-started.html).

Step 1 went fine.

- I'm on Windows.
- I've got Node v.0.10.33
- I've got Ruby 1.9.3p551
- I've got Git 1.9.4.msysgit.2
- I've got Bundler 1.7.7

[image]

What's the issue?

Comment: Can't help, but can say I've got precisely the same error showing, just for confidence's sake. I've gone through all sorts of things sugggested by stackexchange etc. googling, but not cracked it. Something about executing npm install within a script is the problem. It may be a pathing thing, and possibly related to cygwin installation. Zurb so often has these problems. My usual solution is to remove all the Ruby, Node, etc. installs, and then make fresh ones, if I can figure out which versions Zurb is using at the moment. I don't necessarily suggest this. Let's see what they say, early days.

Comment: I think this has to be a path problem in an apparent part of cygwin that's part of nodejs or Ruby. Too late to work it out now. However, I could get the example app built by manually applying the commands in foundationCLI.js. Something like, npm install yApp; cd yApp; bower install; bundle; cd ..; npm start;.  You might have had to run the failing foundation-apps new yApp before this. npm start compiles the initial project, then watches for edits on build/variousthings to recompile. You watch the result from localhost:8080 in browser. This will likely get you going.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also got that error and I replaced following lines in foundationCLI.js and then it worked.
I found this answer on the foundation forum but the post is deleted.

line 94:

```
 var npmInstall = ['npm.cmd', 'install'];
```

line 95:

```
 var bowerInstall = ['bower.cmd', 'install'];
```

line 96:

```
 var bundleInstall = ['bundle.bat'];
```

line 157:

```
 exec(['bower.cmd', 'update', '--production', '--ansi'], function(err, out, code) {
```

line 176:

```
 var proc = spawn('npm.cmd', cmd);
```

Comment: It fixed it! Thank you! (still weird though right?)

Comment: and didn't fix it here, though it makes sense. I tried the first part of this last night, but failed here, and indeed npm is npm, not npm.cmd, on the win64 box. I think there are a number of ways things can fail here, depending on what versions or sources your tools come from. It's a nasty business, and not helped by npm soon to fork, or that Zurb clearly doesn't bother to test on Windows before releasing. Here's their statement, Rafi at the end: http://foundation.zurb.com/forum/posts/21148-foundation-apps-new-myapp-error-on-line-130